# Creating relationships in rails 4 (one model can belong to multiple other models)

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to model links and nodes in Rails 4.  A link can have two nodes (a source node and a target node).  A node can belong to multiple links.  I wrote this in my links model.

```
class Links < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :source_node, class_name: 'Node'
  has_one :target_node, class_name: 'Node'

end
```

I wrote this for my node class.  Is this correct?

```
class Nodes < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :link


end
```

Comment: Why do you ask if it is correct? The design is up to you. Right or wrong depends on what you were expecting as a result and if you got that outcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- SN - source node
- TN - target node
- L - link

Use cases for links:

```
SN - L - TN
SN - L
     L - TN
     L
```

One link **has one** source node.

One link **has one** target node.

Use cases for nodes:

```
     L3  
      |
L1 - SN - L2
      |
     L4
```

One node **has many** links.

So:

```
class Links < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :source_node, class_name: 'Node' // didn't use has_one*
  belongs_to :target_node, class_name: 'Node'
end

class Nodes < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :links
end
```

The reason to use **belongs_to** instead of **has_one** is because Link would have the foreign key to Node.

What if the relationship was defined in the opposite way? One where Node has the foreign key (belongs_to), and Link (has_one) of each type of node. With that design you would need to define a field `link_N_id` for N links in the Node model.

The problems are:

- You have to manually add N fields for N links.
- Relationships are limited to a maximum of N for each node.